# Too many depths in REST result for self relationship of spring-data-neo4j

Tags: rest, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

I have a self relations (a staff can report to a manager and a manager may have many staffs)as follows:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Employee {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    private String name;
    private String sn;
    private String mail;

    public Employee() {
        super();
    }

    public Employee(String name, String sn, String mail) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.sn = sn;
        this.mail = mail;
    }

    @Relationship(type="REPORT_TO", direction=Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Employee manager;

    @Relationship(type="REPORT_TO", direction=Relationship.INCOMING)
    private Set<Employee> staffs = new HashSet<>();

    ...
}
```

I use REST API as the interface of my application. When I try to return all Employee with `session.loadAll(Employee.class, 0)`, it seems everything fine but no manager or staff info will show. On the other hand, if I use `session.loadAll(Employee.class, 0)`, to many depths of Employee are returned.

For example, if employee A reports to employee B, viz. B is the manager of A. The result for depth 0 is :

`{
  "_embedded" : {
    "employees" : [ {
      "name" : "B",
      "sn" : "10001",
      "mail" : "B@test.com",
      "manager" : null,
      "staffs" : [ ],
    }, {
      "name" : "A",
      "sn" : "10000",
      "mail" : "A@test.com",
      "manager" : null,
      "staffs" : [ ],
    } ]
  }
  ...
}`

while the result for depth 1 is :
`[{"id":9,"name":"A","sn":"10000","mail":"A@test.com","manager":{"id":8,"name":"B","sn":"10001","mail":"B@test.com","manager":null,"staffs":[{"id":9,"name":"A","sn":"10000","mail":"A@test.com","manager":{"id":8,"name":"B","sn":"10001","mail":"B@test.com","manager":null,"staffs":[{"id":9,"name":"A","sn":"10000","mail":"A@test.com","manager":{"id":8,"name":"B","sn":"10001","mail":"B@test.com","manager":null,"staffs":[{"id":9,"name":"A","sn":"10000","mail":"A@test.com","manager":{"id":8,"name":"B","sn":"10001","mail":"B@test.com","manager":null,"staffs":[{"id":9,"name":"A","sn":"10000","mail":"A@test.com","manager":{"id":8,"name":"B","sn":"10001","mail":"B@test.com","manager":null,"staffs":[{"id":9,"name":"A","sn":"10000","mail":"A@test.com","manager":{"id":8,"name":"B","sn":"10001","mail":"B@test.com","manager":null,"staffs":[{"id":9,"name":"A","sn":"10000","mail":"A@test.com","manager":{"id":8,"name":"B","sn":"10001","mail":"B@test.com","manager":null,"staffs":[{"id":9,"name":"A","sn":"10000","mail":"A@test.com","manager":{"id":8,"name":"B","sn":"10001","mail":"B@test.com","manager":null,"staffs":[{"id":9,"name":"A","sn":"10000","mail":"A@test.com","manager":{"id":8,"name":"B","sn":"10001","mail":"B@test.com","manager":null,"staffs":[{"id":9,"name":"A","sn":"10000","mail":"A@test.com",...`

How can I handle the case? Could anyone give me some advices, please.

Comment: Is this the result of the OGM loadAll query or the resulting Employee serialized via your rest api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a JSON serialisation issue. The entities contains circular references, and the serialiser is unable to detect them, so it enters an infinite loop constructing the JSON objects. You could try the [JSOG Jackson](https://github.com/jsog/jsog-jackson) plugin, which is able to detect and automatically handle this kind of problem. For an example of how it can be used in a Spring project, have a look at [SDN University](https://github.com/neo4j-examples/sdn4-university/blob/master/src/main/java/school/domain/Entity.java).